# How to get child name in firebase storage using android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

1. I am trying to get a child name but not getting any one please help me.
2. My path is user/pg
3. After pg what is child node, I don't know but that name is required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: These are three quesion in one: you should split those in separate questions. Also, we would like to see some of your code and/or data setup (or an equivalent of them).

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)